# Loading images(require) doesn't work using string variable

Tags: reactjs

Requiring image with string variable doesn't work:

```
// working
var texture = require('./images/imag_01.jpg');


// doesn't work
path = './images/imag_01.jpg';
var texture = require(path);

// Error: Cannot find module "."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` doesn't accept a variable.

But you can do so with a [dynamic import() statement](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import) should you need to import dynamically, if you are using ES6.

*** Update: 2018.11.19 ***

React v16.6 introduced [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy), which you can use to split code more easily.

Answer (score 3):

It is not your fault, it is how it is, unfortunatetly, supposed to work. You must write require('image-path') and cannot have a variable inside the parenthesis.

See: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var image_name = 'imag_01.jpg';
var texture = require('./images/'+image_name );
```

Comment: it returns' Cannot find module './undefined''